# why toggle() in jQuery not working for div

Tags: jquery

for span toggle() is working fine, because of inline and none display properties,
Div supports block and none, so how to use toggle()? or give me a suitable way...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/92etk5d2/ what's not working for you in this example

Answer (score 0):

For supporting in `toggle(`) in your code, you need to Add `jquery.js` file in the head section of your html code, you can download the jquery file from [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js)